# Вывод сообщений из базы

Tags: php

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемкой. Есть сайт, где пользователи могут обмениваться сообщениями, но как вывести переписку? у меня получается выводить или то что я ему отправил, или то что он мне, а как сделать что бы и то и это выводилось и в верном парядке? но только `ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда задаёте вопрос, по выборке из БД, хорошо бы структуру таблицы прилагать.
Попробую погадать на недопитом кофе.

Наверно в вашей таблице (скажем **messages**) есть поле ID отправителя (например **from_user_id**) и ID получателя (что-то вроде **to_user_id**) Если все так, то вам нужен примерно такой запрос:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    messages
WHERE
    (from_user_id = 'ID_ОТПРАВИТЕЛЯ' AND to_user_id = 'ID_ПОЛУЧАТЕЛЯ') OR
    (to_user_id   = 'ID_ОТПРАВИТЕЛЯ' AND from_user_id = 'ID_ПОЛУЧАТЕЛЯ')
ORDER BY id DESC
```